# Using only the grid component of Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

Is it possible to just use the grid component of Bootstrap 3?

I saw many grid frameworks that are customizable but not as flexible as Bootstrap (only 1 breakpoint for small/large devices, no medium size device).

Or is there any responsive grid framework written in SASS that is customizable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one alternative: Gridle, http://olivierbossel.github.io/gridle/demo.html